# JQuery Show/Hide additional changes

Tags: jquery, animation, prototypejs

I have the following JQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $j(".follow_btn")
         .click(
        function() {
                var element = $(this);
                var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "action/follow.php?friend_id=<?php echo $row_inactive_user_settings['user_id']; ?>",
                data : info,
                success : function() {
                }
            });
            $("#sb_follow" + I).hide();
            $("#sb_unfollow" + I).show();
            return false;
        });
     });
jQuery(function($) {
    $j(".unfollow_btn").click(
        function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "action/unfollow.php?friend_id=<?php echo $row_inactive_user_settings['user_id']; ?>",
                data : info,
                success : function() {
                    }
            });
            $("#sb_unfollow" + I).hide();
            $("#sb_follow" + I).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and following HTML code which trigger above JQuery:

```
<div id="sb_follow1"
<?php if ($totalRows_sb_track > 0) { echo 'style="display:none"';}?>>
    <a href="#" class="follow_btn" id="1">Follow</a>
</div>
<div id="sb_unfollow1"
<?php if ($totalRows_sb_track == 0) { echo 'style="display:none"';}?>>
    <a href="#" class="unfollow_btn" id="1">unFollow</a>
</div>
```

now what I need is to after I click on "Follow" link from above HTML code to show below container:

```
<dl id="subscribe">
 <ul id="ulg">
    <li>List one</li>
    <li>List two</li>
    <li>List three</li>
 </ul>
</dl>
```

And when I click on "unFollow" to hide that container I want to keep above JQuery code but also add this additional function. If someone is able to do necessary changes in above JQuery code that would be lovely. I also want to note that I have attached Prototype.js file to my pages.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable. Also, what have you tried and where are you having a problem?

Comment: @Spikey21 just gave me the changes i was looking for :)

Comment: Still, it is appreciated when you ask for help that you spend a little time formatting your question.

Comment: sorry for that, will keep that on mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery would look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $j(".follow_btn")
            .click(
                    function() {
                        var element = $(this);
                        var I = element.attr("id");
                        var info = 'id=' + I;
                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "action/follow.php?friend_id=<?php echo $row_inactive_user_settings['user_id']; ?>",
                                    data : info,
                                    success : function() {
                                    }
                                });
                        $("#sb_follow" + I).hide();
                        $("#sb_unfollow" + I).show();
                        $("#subscribe").show();
                        return false;
                    });
});
jQuery(function($) {
    $j(".unfollow_btn")
            .click(
                    function() {
                        var element = $(this);
                        var I = element.attr("id");
                        var info = 'id=' + I;
                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    type : "POST",
                                    url : "action/unfollow.php?friend_id=<?php echo $row_inactive_user_settings['user_id']; ?>",
                                    data : info,
                                    success : function() {
                                    }
                                });
                        $("#sb_unfollow" + I).hide();
                        $("#sb_follow" + I).show();
                        $("#subscribe").hide();
                        return false;
                    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for help, works great, also thank for formatting my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#subscribe').show()` within `$j(".follow_btn").click(....)` and  `$('#subscribe').hide()` within `$j(".unfollow_btn").click(...)` It's pretty basic, have a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)